# How to make specific items only appear in recto pages in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, double-sided, context-mkiv

I would like for some items in my book to begin only on recto, or right-hand pages, such as, e.g.:

- The first page.
- The table of contents.
- The beginning of a `\part`.

I believe such a configuration is a default in most LaTeX document classes. How can I ensure that all of these items are placed on recto pages in ConTeXt?

Comment: Set doublesided layout and use `\page[right]`

Comment: You might also use the `\definepagebreak` mechanism. For an example see [Context wiki - Titles](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Titles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Aditya already pointed out, using a doublesided layout is necessary. Otherwise there is no concept of a right page. By default the first page, the table of contents (when `\completecontent` is used) and the parts already start on a right page.

However, the placement is customizable. All structure head commands have a `page` key that either take `left`, `right`, `yes` or a page break definition as an argument. For more details see the [ConTeXt wiki - Titles](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Titles#Truly_empty_pagebreak_before_chapters). Using a `\definepagebreak` definition is more powerful, since you can set the page headers as well.

And you can always use the [`\page`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/page) command in your document. To separate content and layout I would advice to avoid the use of direct instructions like `\page` if possible.

**Example:**

```
% switch from singlesided to doublesided layout
\setuppagenumbering [alternative=doublesided]

% you have lots of options to influence the appearence of the page
% \definepagebreak [chapterpagebreak] [yes, header, right]
\definepagebreak   [chapterpagebreak] [right]

% either use a page break definition
\setuphead [chapter] [page=chapterpagebreak]

% or a direct instruction without page break definition
% \setuphead [chapter] [page=right]

\setuphead [part]    [page=right, placehead=yes]

\starttext

  \startstandardmakeup [align=middle, style=\bfd]
    First page
  \stopstandardmakeup

  \completecontent

  \startpart [title=Part one]
    \startchapter [title=First]
      \input ward
    \stopchapter

    \startchapter [title=Second]
      \input ward
    \stopchapter
  \stoppart

\stoptext
```